# Regex Extract a string between two words containing a particular string

Tags: regex

I have the below string

```
abc-12d-ef-oy-5678-xyz--**--20190120075439322am--**--ghi-66d-ef-oy-8877-sdf--**--sfdfdsgfg--**--20190120075765487am
```

It is kind of multi character delimited string, delimited by '--**--' I am trying to extract the first and second words which has the -oy- tag in it. This is a column in a table. I am using the regex_extract method but i am not able extract the string which contains a string and ends with a string.

Here is one pattern that i tried `.*(.*oy.*)--`

Comment: Here is one patter that i have tried  .*(.*oy.*)--

Comment: The correct pattern you need to use is `^(.*?)--\*\*--(.*?)--\*\*--` where group1 and group2 captures your respectively text. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FLYFG4/1)

Comment: Hi @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi The above pattern is grouping the text between delimiters but how can we add the condition that it contains -oy- as a part of it. Thank you so much for the help. Will try from my end as well

Comment: Do you want to reject match if any of the groups does not contain `-oy-`?

Comment: yes exactly that's what i am looking for

Comment: I've added an answer with a regex exactly as you described. Hope that works for you and let me know in case you have any other query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189222/discussion-between-dileep-gog-and-pushpesh-kumar-rajwanshi).

Answer (score 2):

If the `-oy-` can not be at the start or at the end, you could use this pattern to match the 2 hyphen delimited strings with -oy-:

```
[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*-oy(?:-[a-z0-9]+)+
```

**Regex details**

- `[a-z0-9]+` Match 1+ times a-z0-9
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `-[a-z0-9]+` Match `-` and 1+ times a-z0-9
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `-oy` Match literally
- `(?:-[a-z0-9]+)+` Repeat 1+ times a group which will match `-` and 1+ times a-z0-9

You can extend the character class `[A-Za-z0-9]` to allow what you want to match like uppercase chars.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b0qfJ8/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/gJL8yw)

If the matches should be between delimiters, you could use a positive lookbehind and positive lookahead and an alternation:

```
(?<=^|--\\*\\*--)[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*-oy(?:-[a-z0-9]+)+(?=--\\*\\*--|$)
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/TqdVoh)

Comment: This does not answer what OP wants. He wants to reject the match if text in group1 and group2 strictly between the delimiters does not contain `-oy-`. Your regex does not even consider the delimiters OP has mentioned.[See this](https://regex101.com/r/b0qfJ8/2)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I added a version which uses lookarounds to take the delimiter into account. The question stated `I am trying to extract the first and second words which has the -oy- tag in it.` and that is what my answer is based on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex which will match string containing `-oy-` and capture them in group1 and group2.

```
^.*?(\w+(?:-\w+)*-oy-\w+(?:-\w+)*).*?(\w+(?:-\w+)*-oy-\w+(?:-\w+)*)
```

This regex basically matches two strings delimiter separated containing `-oy-` using this `(\w+(?:-\w+)*-oy-\w+(?:-\w+)*)` to capture the text.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EO4Gor/1/)**

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped solving the problem

Comment: In the Demo link why isn't the 1st and 3rd line didn't have a match. can you please explain a bit more

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to select values from capture groups?

`(?:--\*\*--|^)(.*?-oy-.*?)(?:--\*\*--|$)`

?: - Non-capture group, matches the delimiter, begin of line, or end of line but does not create a capture group

*? - Lazy match so you only grab the contents of the field

https://regex101.com/r/aUAvcx/1

--- Second stab at this follows ---

This is convoluted. Hopefully you can use Lookahead and Lookbehind. The last problem I had was the final record was being "Greedy" and sucking up the field before it too. So I had to add an exclusion in the capture group for your delimiter.

See if this works for you.

`(?<=--\*\*--|^)((?:(?:(?!--\*\*--).)*)-oy-(?:(?:(?!--\*\*--).)*))(?=--\*\*--|$)`

https://regex101.com/r/aUAvcx/3

Basically the (?: are so we are not getting too many capture groups to work with.

There are three parts to this:

1. The lookbehind - Make sure the field is framed by the delimiter (or start of line)
2. The capture group - Grab the contents of the field, making sure a delimiter isn't sucked up into it
3. The lookahead - Make sure the field is framed by the delimiter (or end of line)

As far as the capture group goes, I check the left and right side of the -oy- to make sure the delimiter isn't there.

Comment: Thank you so much @curtis with your pattern the required string are coming as 2 matches and the first group of each match can we get things into two groups and if my -oy- string is in the second word of the delimited string, It is not able to match properly